# Can I use the word “young” in this situation?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Is *young* the correct word in the following context?

> First of all, I plan to participate in building the Italian eGovernment. The Italian eGovernment is still **young** and we need to work for many years in many stages in order to achieve it.

Would it be better to use *small* or *tiny* instead?

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you told us more about what you are trying to say. Neither _young_ nor _small_ is incorrect, but the former emphasizes the newness of something, while the latter emphasizes potential for expansion and growth.

Comment: Minor stylistic suggestion: "First of all" is redundant; just say "First."  First is always "of all"--else it's not first. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *young* is appropriate in that context, since one of the meaning of the word is "having lived or existed for only a short time; not fully developed." The part that applies in that case is "not fully developed."

*Small* is used also as synonym of *young*, but (as far as I can see) it is used for humans or animals. *Tiny* is used only in the context of size or amount, such as *a tiny baby* or *a tiny minority*.

Comment: @Marco - I usually suggest waiting 12 to 24 hours before accepting an answer. Sometimes a better answer will come along. I've even seen a few cases where an answer was accepted even though it was clearly wrong! In this case, I don't find fault with kia's answer, but, as a matter of practice, I recommend letting your question get wider exposure before accepting an answer. There's no rush.